# Rational homogenous spaces and symmetric spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

What are the complex rational homogenous spaces $G/P$ ($G$ a semi-simple complex Lie group, $P$ a parabolic subgroup) such that the set of real points $(G/P)(\mathbb R)$ is a (compact) riemannian symmetric space?

This is certainly well-known by the experts, but I'm not one of them...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you clarify: what do mean by "is"? $(G/P)(\mathbf{R})$ is a set, a topological space, a real analytic manifold... A compact riemannian symmetric space is a metric space, a Riemannian manifold, a topological space, a real analytic manifold...

Comment: My confusion is what are "real points"? There is no ${\mathbb R}$-structure on $G/P$, a priori, unless $G$ and $P$ are defined over $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compact Riemannian symmetric spaces admitting a Lie group of
diffeomorphisms $G$ properly containing the isometry group are essentialy (up to covers) the symmetric $R$-spaces, which are of the form $G/P$. This is a celebrated theorem of Nagano [Nag, Theorem 3.1].

The list of these spaces is e.g. in the appendix of [Isothermic submanifolds of symmetric $R$-spaces](http://www.sfbtr71.de/publications/pedit_isothermic.pdf) (pdf).

[Nag] Tadashi Nagano, Transformation groups on compact symmetric spaces, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 118 (1965),
428–453. MR0182937

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not entirely clear to me what the OP means by $(G/P)(\mathbb{R})$, but the Nagano's theorem should bring him closer to answer in any case.

Comment: Vit Tucek's answer is a precise and relevant answer to my confusing question! Thanks a lot.

Comment: A question concerning the terminology: to what refers the "R" in "R-space"?

Comment: I have no idea. And it's pretty hard to google. :)

Comment: R is for "racine".  Terminology coined by Jacques Tits, I believe.

Comment: Thanks! What do these spaces have to do with roots?